# How to join more than one column between 2 tables

Tags: sql, join, union

I am currently having trouble with learning SQL, and am unable to get a table to join to another one when two or more of the columns in both tables are the same.

For example, I have 2 tables:

(I'm not sure how to post the code so I've just posted a link I hope that this is ok)

This is table 1, it shows how long each stage of each Project will take 
http://puu.sh/gt92M/3dfe0063f0.png

This is table 2, it shows how long the stage of each project has been worked upon

http://puu.sh/gt9HO/2fd5090c9a.png

So far I have been able to put them into the same table, but I am unable to get the hours taken into its own column, currently they mix with the hours needed column.

```
SELECT ID, Stage, SUM(Hours_Taken)
FROM Work
GROUP BY ID, Stage
UNION
SELECT ID, Stage, Hours
FROM Budget_Allocation
GROUP BY ID, Stage
```

As you can see, each project has stages, and each stage needs a different amount of work hours. I want to be able to display a 4 columned table:

```
ID    
Stage   
Hours    
Hours_Taken.
```

Comment: you can just list whem within join: SELECT * FROM ti JOIN t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1 AND t1.col1=ta.col2

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a result whose columns include some derived from one table and others derived from a different table.  That means you need to perform some kind of `JOIN`.  The `UNION` operator does **not** join tables, it just collates multiple row sets into a single row set, eliminating duplicates.

One of the rowsets you want to select from is not a base table, however, but rather the result of an aggregate query.  This calls for a subquery, the results of which you join to the other base table as needed:

```
SELECT
  tw.ID AS ID,
  tw.Stage AS Stage,
  ba.Hours AS Hours,
  tw.Hours_Taken AS Hours_Taken
FROM
  Budget_Allocation ba
  -- JOIN operator --
  JOIN (
    -- here's the subquery --
    SELECT ID, Stage, SUM(Hours_Taken) AS Hours_Taken
    FROM Work
    GROUP BY ID, Stage
  ) tw
    -- predicate for the preceding JOIN operator --
    ON ba.ID = tw.ID AND ba.Stage = tw.Stage
```

Note that in this case you do not want to join base tables first and then aggregate rows of the joint results, because you are selecting values from one column (`Budget_Allocation.Hours`) that is neither a grouping column nor a function of the groups.  There are workarounds and implementation-specific exceptions to that limitation, but in this case it's easy to do the right thing straight off by aggregating before joining.

Comment: Ok I understand kinda. Is it common practice to set the selects as aliases?  I dont want to get into any bad habits :)

Comment: You should use aliases for select items that don't naturally have a meaningful name, such as expressions and function results.  You must use aliases under certain other circumstances.  Otherwise, it's a style issue.  I tend to use aliases whenever I select a column by its qualified name, though I don't think it's always *necessary* to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing union instead of join.

select w.id,w.stage,w.hours_taken, b.hours
from work w, budge_allocation b
where w.id = b.id and
w.stage = b.stage;

now you have everything you need in one row and can do what you want with it.

Comment: Ah I see, so you can do joins by using where * = *?